# Formatted text, code block in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net, text-formatting

I want to add JSON code snippets to my diagram in draw.io. When I use copy/paste to a text box, the indented spaces/tabs get lost.

Does anyone know how to copy formatted snippets from notepad++/VS Code to draw.io?

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert tabs into spaces in Notepad++. It should do the trick.

If you don't know how consult [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455037/5142901) question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

you can see from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LI4OqHut4YI. who can develop into a plugin?